# How to refresh table within a popup in dialog window in ADF Oracle 11gR1

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm working on a requirement to show a popup window with search table in it. As the user clicks on the search button (with input text boxes provided) in the popup window the search table needs to be refreshed with new set of data.

I've created a `populateSearchTable()` method to generate the table by populating the values in an Array `deviceListArray<POJO CLass>`.

In `populatesearchTable()` every time I generate the data I'm trying to clear the deviceList Array by `deviceListArray.Clear()` method and also used the below method to refresh the table at the end of it.

```
 AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(<tableBindingVariable>)
```

For some reason the table does not get refreshed. Let me know if I need to share my code.

Is there any other way to refresh a table with in a popup which is different from normal refresh method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After declaring your list and creating the setter and getter.

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String>();
```

when you do the search, fill the list with the result data , then put it in the 
**ProcessScope** like

```
for(....){

mylist.add(....)
}
```

`AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getProcessScope().put("mylist", mylist)`;

Rewrite the get method for the list to as follows :

```
public List<String> getMyList() {
        myList.clear();
        List<String> list = (List<String>) AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getProcessScope().get("myList");
        if (list != null) {
            for (String var : list) {
                myList.add(var);
            }
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

And make sure to set the value for the table to the list :

```
  <af:table value="#{SomeBean.myList}" var="row" rowBandingInterval="0" ..... />
```

Regards

Salam... :)

Comment: Exception in Invoking populating Search Device Table :- java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ScopeMap.get(ScopeMap.java:67)
        at com.avocent.trellis.citirenamedevice.ui.table.PopulatePopUpSearchDeviceTable.populateDeviceTable(PopulatePopUpSearchDeviceTable.java:95)

Comment: I get this error when I click on the table... when the table value is set to "{SomeBean.myList}".. If I change it back "{bindings.Iterator.CollentionModel}" the table does not get refreshed... but I'm able to select the values in the table...with no error... please help me in getting table refreshed

Comment: I think you one of the columns has a binding attribute that is not exist in the list for example :

Comment: your object for the list is **Employee** : **userId, name, email**.

Comment: one of the columns will be :
`<af:column sortable="false" headerText="Email " ... >
                                                                <af:outputText value="#{row.email}" id="ot93"/>
                                                            </af:column>`

Comment: let us say you changed the the list to another Employee Class that does not have the **email** attribute then an exception will be raised in casting  cause of the following binding that does not exist in the object 
`value="#{row.email}"`