# ADF: table was unable to show in page

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an ADF table defined in a .jsff file, in which the partialTrigger is bound to the id of the component containing class **B**:

```
    <af:table value="#{pageFlowScope.ManagedBeanName.nameList}"  
    ...        
    partialTriggers="::::it5">
    ...
    </af:table>
```

In the ManagedBeanName.java, we define the **nameList** and have a method to set value to the list named **setNameList**. When the nameList is set with value, it will show the table in the UI page.

```
public void setNameList(){
     ...
     nameList.add(name);
}
```

Now I have a Class **B**, in which we invoke **setNameList**,

```
ManagedBeanName managedbean = new ManagedBeanName();
managedbean.setNameList();
```

Through the debugging process, we found setNameList can be invoked correctly and nameList can be set values.

But after the invoking, nameList does not have values. And the table does not show.

Could you please help to discover where the issue is?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I define the setNameList() in managedbean and have to invoke setNameList() in another method in Class B.

I new a fresh managedBean to call this method and the nameList in this instance is not the one bonded to the page.

**Solution**:

In class B, get the right instance as:

```
ManagedBean managedBean = (ManagedBean)ADFUtil.evaluateEL("#{pageFlowScope.ManagedBean}");
```

The issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put list of data in a scope
try something like this:

```
public List<String> getMyList() {
        myList.clear();
        List<String> list = (List<String>) AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getProcessScope().get("myList");
        if (list != null) {
            for (String var : list) {
                myList.add(var);
            }
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

**You can also see this question and answer :**

[How to refresh table within a popup in dialog window in ADF Oracle 11gR1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201592/how-to-refresh-table-within-a-popup-in-dialog-window-in-adf-oracle-11gr1/41201765#41201765)

Comment: Hi Belal, thanks for your reply. It seems that there's a small difference in the two cases. In my case, I define the setNameList() in managedbean and have to invoke setNameList() in anther method in Class B. So I need to new a managedBean to call this method, which causes the problem. Because nameList in the new managedBean is not the one bonded to the page. Could you provide some advice on it? Thanks very much!